# How can I exclude from my Facebook news feed posts containing some keywords?

Tags: facebook

Facebook does not allow that natively, maybe there exist some browser extensions or other tricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/)** or **[F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/)** allows that.

To configure Social Fixer to block news feed posts containing certain keywords, go to Social Fixer options » Filtering. In FB Purity, go to FB Purity options » Custom Text Filter.

There are detailed instructions on using the keyword filtering features of [Social Fixer here](http://lifehacker.com/5940319/how-to-block-annoying-political-posts-on-facebook) and [here](http://socialfixer.com/feed_filter.php), and for [FB Purity,  here](http://www.fbpurity.com/extras.htm#customtextfilter).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! And obviously, those Facebook morons are [trying to shut down F.B. Purity](https://www.facebook.com/fluffbustingpurity/posts/10151343764432559)...